# Convert a shapefile (.shp) to xml/json

Tags: xml, gis, file-format

I'm working with a shapefile (.shp, .dbf, etc) and would like to convert it to xml. I'm on a mac, and I'm having trouble finding an application that will help me with the conversion. Does anyone know of a method for converting this file format into an xml file?

Comment: Also you can try to use http://techslides.com/demos/mapping/shapefile-geojson-converter.html It is online and works fine for me.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

What dassouki said. Get GDAL from http://www.kyngchaos.com/software:frameworks. Use it to convert a shapefile to [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org) like this:

```
$ ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" output.json input.shp
```

eg

```
$ ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" /tmp/world.json world_borders.shp world_borders
$ cat /tmp/world.json
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "CAT": 1.000000, "FIPS_CNTRY": "AA",
  "CNTRY_NAME": "Aruba", "AREA": 193.000000, "POP_CNTRY": 71218.000000 }, 
  "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -69.882233, ...
  ...
```

Comment: Also exists in homebrew! `brew install gdal`

Comment: Any tips on getting an `xml` output?

Comment: This worked for some huge shapefiles (~500MB), where others crashed (eg QGIS)

Comment: This works great! Just don't forget to add projection if used for OpenStreetMap as argument:
-t_srs crs:84

Answer (score 46):

[GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/) is your friend. Use the ogr2ogr libraries, and here's [a cheat sheet](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=ogr_cheatsheet).

If you want a good GIS application, install [QGIS](http://qgis.org) and download the gdal converter plugin

Answer (score 31):

I've found this website that converts loads of Geo formats: http://mygeodata.eu/apps/converter/index_en.html

In less than 2 minutes I was able to convert a ShapeFile zip to a GeoJson file!

(I was trying GDAL at the same time and it's still downloading...)

Comment: Why you have passed the shapefile's name without any extension (highlighted with bold) as last parameter in the following command? ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" /tmp/world.json world_borders.shp **world_borders**

Comment: Thank you for this link.  I was able to take a series of shape file outputs and convert them to GeoJSON instantly.

Comment: This was the easiest solution for me.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: link is now dead (404), try http://converter.mygeodata.eu/ although the tool didn't work for me

Answer (score 8):

This online converter worked for me

http://mapshaper.org/

I uploaded my  .shp file, Then exported it to GeoJson.

Answer (score 3):

I can also offer a very round about answer.

Put geoserver on your machine (you can download a self contained zip file)

Set up a datastore that points to your shapefile.

Set up a layer that points to your datastore

Go to the preview layers page and ask for a WFS as GML preview

Voila - an xml representation of your shapefile.