# GeoJson World Database

Tags: svg, d3.js, geojson

I am working on a project where it is necessary to display maps of countries and cities using d3.js.

Actually, D3 supports GeoJson format. Usually, I guess, GeoJson format is converted from some other format.

I found some places with this GeoJson data:

http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/countries.js

But, this is only a list of countries, I am looking for some service or program that gives me the ability to set an ID, get this format, and convert it to GeoJson, or get it in GeoJson better.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Does this need to be a service? Here's how I've approached this in the past, using free/Open Source tools:

- Download public-domain shape files from [Natural Earth Data](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/)
- Use [Quantum GIS](http://www.qgis.org/) to convert .shp to .geojson (one step, under "Layer > Save As...")

Now you have hi-res GeoJSON data.

This is a really big file, though, so you'll want to split it up. But you don't need a service for this, just static files for each country, named by ID. This would be easy enough to produce with a script in your utility of choice (Python, Ruby, node.js).

Comment: To those who need a more elaborate answer: 1. Download map from Natural Earth Data. 2. Unzip and find the Shape file. 3. Drag shape file to QGIS. 4. "Layer > Save As" as above.

Comment: faster : convert online at https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/shp-to-geojson

Answer (score 15):

Note that, via the [GDAL library](http://www.gdal.org/index.html), you may also use the command-line `ogr2ogr` to convert shapefiles. For example:

```
$ ogr2ogr -f geojson source_file.shp dst_file.json
```

will convert `source_file.shp` into the GeoJSON-formatted `dst_file.json`.

Read more here:

[Convert a shapefile (.shp) to xml/json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223979/convert-a-shapefile-shp-to-xml-json)

Comment: The command may have changed.  I used `ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" output.json input.shp`

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at https://github.com/mledoze/countries

It has geoJSONs for each country. (med resolution I would say)

`countries.json` contain each country description including localized country names, coordinate (at which you can display the label), and capitals names.

Answer (score 2):

Some good folks made the shapefile to geojson formatter an online service.

Check the following link:
http://ogre.adc4gis.com/

They even open-sourced it: http://github.com/wavded/ogre