# Build map in D3

Tags: javascript, dictionary, d3.js

I would like to build a visualization such as in:

http://bl.ocks.org/2206590

But this example shows the united states. Can I do this visualization for another country? If yes, how can I do this?

Comment: If you open the example in a new window and inspect the XHR request you will notice that the data is sourced by d3 from a file called [`readme.json`](http://bl.ocks.org/d/2206590/readme.json) containing data for all states of the US. This data is then processed by d3.js. In case you want to do something similar for another country you'll need to get similar data for that.

Comment: D3 includes utilities for processing the GeoJSON format. So you'll need to get geo data in GeoJSON format for the country you're interested in. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542834/geojson-world-database/9591494#9591494