# large shp file to JSON

Tags: json, shapefile

Hello I'm working a large shp file and i want to convert into JSON file. It's of 100MB size. I found some online converting sites but i'm having trouble uploading a 100MB file.

So do we some other better way of doing that for eg. some offline methods?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223979/convert-a-shapefile-shp-to-xml-json

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 actually i went through that link but i couldn't understand...