# Converting a shapefile to json, xml or osm and NOT Geojson

Tags: json, gis, geojson, gdal, shapefile

I have an amended road network shape file (`.shp`) that I need to convert to json/xml/osm format (any of the following is fine). I am unable to use files with .geojson extension as the function, I am trying to use for my task doesn't accept this format  (function `OpenStreetMapSpace()` from the `agents.jl`package, url : https://juliadynamics.github.io/Agents.jl/stable/api/#Agents.OpenStreetMapSpace)

I followed the following post ([Convert a shapefile (.shp) to xml/json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223979/convert-a-shapefile-shp-to-xml-json)) and converted my `.shp` file to a `.json` file. However the file that is produced is a GeoJSON file as mentioned by "GeoJSON" (even though it has a `.json` extension).

`ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" output.json input.shp`

The produced `output.json` file doesn't work with function i mentioned above and throws an error saying `elements` not found. And so it seems the function requires `.json` file.

Any idea on how to convert .shp file to a `.json`, `.osm` or `.xml` file? (As any of these file formats are mentioned to work with this function)